# Same length for line in frame title and foot line

Tags: beamer, header-footer, frame-title

How can I make sure that the two red lines have the same length?

I am learning to use beamer and I want to modify something. As you see in the figure, two red lines do not have the same length even I use similar codes:

[image]

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vskip0.3cm
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
    \vskip-1.5ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% Remove navigation


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\textwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.3cm
}
```

The full code is below

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported

%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{default}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[About Beamer] %optional
{About the Beamer class in presentation making}

\subtitle{A short story}

\author[Arthur, Doe] % (optional)
{A.~B.~Arthur\inst{1} \and J.~Doe\inst{2}}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Faculty of Physics\\
  Very Famous University
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Faculty of Chemistry\\
  Very Famous University
}

\date[VLC 2014] % (optional)
{Very Large Conference, April 2014}

%\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{lion-logo.jpg}}

%End of title page configuration block
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line foot}{bg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vskip0.3cm
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
    \vskip-1.5ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% Remove navigation


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\textwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.3cm
}


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{First section}

%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in second frame. For the sake of showing an example.

\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Text visible on slide 1
    \item<2-> Text visible on slide 2
    \item<3> Text visible on slides 3
    \item<4-> Text visible on slide 4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: which of the two lengths would you like to have?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks for reading. I would have the same length for the red line below the frame title and the red line at the end of the slide.

Answer (score 1):

The footline does not have the normal text margins, but you can compensate these lengths manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported

%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usecolortheme{default}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page
\title[About Beamer] %optional
{About the Beamer class in presentation making}

\subtitle{A short story}

\author[Arthur, Doe] % (optional)
{A.~B.~Arthur\inst{1} \and J.~Doe\inst{2}}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Faculty of Physics\\
  Very Famous University
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Faculty of Chemistry\\
  Very Famous University
}

\date[VLC 2014] % (optional)
{Very Large Conference, April 2014}

%\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{lion-logo.jpg}}

%End of title page configuration block
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line foot}{bg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vskip0.3cm
    \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
    \vskip-1.5ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}% Remove navigation


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace*{1cm}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.75pt, wd=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.3cm
}


\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}


%---------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code is for the table of contents after
%the title page
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------


\section{First section}

%---------------------------------------------------------
%Changing visivility of the text
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in second frame. For the sake of showing an example.

\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Text visible on slide 1
    \item<2-> Text visible on slide 2
    \item<3> Text visible on slides 3
    \item<4-> Text visible on slide 4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I am curious how you know exact lengths in centimeters when you set **\hspace*{1cm}%** and **wd=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax**.

Comment: @TDT 1cm is the default text margin for beamer

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot!

Comment: @TDT You're welcome!